SetWindowDisplayAffinity causes window to be black in screen recorders
I am using DLL injection to execute SetWindowDisplayAffinity on other processes. I use WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE to fully hide the windows in screen recorders.
It works fine at first. But if I hide the target program (currently, Electron apps) to tray and then show its window, screen recorders will see a black window (just like WDA_MONITOR)
System: Windows 11 Pro 23H2
My code:
#include "library.h"

#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

auto createdWindows = std::vector<HWND>();

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    DWORD windowPID = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &windowPID);

    DWORD currentPID = GetCurrentProcessId();

    if (windowPID == currentPID) {
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT idTimer, DWORD dwTime) {
    for (auto hWnd : createdWindows) {
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);
    }

    createdWindows.clear();
}

void StartTimer() {
    SetTimer(nullptr, 0, 1000, reinterpret_cast<TIMERPROC>(TimerProc));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND) {
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetWindowHook() {
    SetWindowsHookExA(WH_CBT, WindowProcHook, nullptr, GetCurrentThreadId());
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpvReserved )  // reserved
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    SetWindowHook();
    StartTimer();

    return TRUE;
}


It is not safe to call EnumWindows() or SetTimer() inside of DllMain(), see Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices: "You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain: ... Call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized."

Just because you know how to start a fight doesn't mean you'll win the fight.

Whether have you tried to use SetWindowDisplayAffinity in normal Win32 applications (like Notepad).

I suggest you could refer to the sample: https://github.com/radiantly/Invisiwind/

@Jeaninez-MSFT It's normal in applications with basic (i guess so) GUI, it does work. When the situation comes to applications such as Electron apps and some games, it then failed to fully hide the window.

It seems an issue for SetWindowDisplayAffinity in win11. I suggest you could Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app
